# Where to ARC Welder extrude “minidump file(.dmp)”?

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-arc

Im debugging Android app(emulating by ARC welder) on Chromebook, and often get `"plugin crashed: captured minidump"` message.

But I dont know where to extrude the "minidump".

https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/packages/crash-reporting/debugging-a-minidump
I saw this link, however  cant find "minidumpfile(foo.dmp)".
In my Chromebook, only those binary files in directory(/usr/bin/).

```
core2md, minidump-2-core, minidump_upload, minidump_dump, minidump_stackwalk
```

Because I cant find dumpfile, cant extrude corefile.
What am I missing? What should I do?

How do you debug ARC minidump?

Answer (score 0):

Generate core file
Convert a minidump to a core file.

```
sh -c '~/chromiumos/chroot/usr/bin/minidump-2-core -v upload_file_minidump-7adc2ee0079cb374.dmp > minidump.core 2>minidump.core.out'
```

For a minidump from a 32-bit executable, use minidump-2-core.32 instead.

For an ARM minidump, you have to work a little bit harder to get a core file. The easiest way is probably to do the conversion using qemu within your chroot.

```
# Convert minidump to a core file in /tmp/
SYSROOT=/build/daisy
qemu-arm \
 ${SYSROOT}/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 \
 --library-path {SYSROOT}/lib: {SYSROOT}/usr/lib \
 ${SYSROOT}/usr/bin/minidump-2-core \
    -v ~/test/upload_file_minidump-de1f11232d825812.dmp >/tmp/minidump.core 2>/tmp/minidump.core.out
```

Reference: http://crosbug.com/34938

Comment: My chromebook is x86 machine, so I tried that command.
But only got error message "sh: cannot create minidump.core: Read-only file system".
Also I tried in superuser mode, but received same message.
Is it Reference truly correct?